# How do I find consecutive values between two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a dataset looking like this:

```
Var1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
Var2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
value <- c(0.000, 7906.818, 27243.707, 26824.343, 7906.818, 0.000, 34109.213, 34162.103, 27243.707, 34109.213, 0.000, 4172.058, 26824.343, 34162.103, 4172.058, 0.000)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(Var1, Var2, value))

> d
   Var1 Var2     value
1     1    1     0.000
2     2    1  7906.818
3     3    1 27243.707
4     4    1 26824.343
5     1    2  7906.818
6     2    2     0.000
7     3    2 34109.213
8     4    2 34162.103
9     1    3 27243.707
10    2    3 34109.213
11    3    3     0.000
12    4    3  4172.058
13    1    4 26824.343
14    2    4 34162.103
15    3    4  4172.058
16    4    4     0.000
```

And what I'm looking for is a way to **remove consecutive values in the two columns**, that is, e.g. if `Var1=1` and `Var2=2`, or `Var1=2` and `Var2=3`, those rows should be removed. This would be included in a loop, as there are multiple sequences like this one.

The output dataframe would be like this:

```
   Var1 Var2     value
1     1    1     0.000
2     2    1  7906.818
3     3    1 27243.707
4     4    1 26824.343
6     2    2     0.000
7     3    2 34109.213
8     4    2 34162.103
9     1    3 27243.707
11    3    3     0.000
12    4    3  4172.058
13    1    4 26824.343
14    2    4 34162.103
16    4    4     0.000
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: With `dplyr` you could use `filter(abs(Var1 - Var2) != 1)` to remove rows with consecutive values in either direction. Or `filter(Var2 - Var1 != 1)` to strictly remove rows where `Var2` is one greater than `Var1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
d[ d$Var2 - d$Var1 != 1, ]
```